# exchange vs google apps

Tags: email, g-suite, exchange

after a couple issues with exchange nad outbound email, the presidents of my company want to switch to google apps...

i know nothing about google apps, and im pretty familiar with exchange

they want to know the benefits of going to google apps vs the down side of leaving exchange

can anyone help me in explaining this, or know of a website where i can read about google apps (non google site, companies often boast services more than necessary)

thanks

Looking for information about Apps vs Exchange not hosted vs internal

thanks!

company info:

around 100 mailboxes
very active directory dependent
alot of security groups and distribution groups (30+)
alot of inhouse software the utilizes the exchange server

Comment: a) no. b) google apps don't display more info than necessary when describing the setup. c) google apps are definitely the way to go if you've got less than many hundreds of employees.

Comment: Have you considered a hosted version of Exchange?  Is your question more about functionality of Google Apps vs Exchange, or is it more about in-house vs hosted.

Comment: apologize - apps vs exchange. we where looking at a cloud 'exchange server' in the past. owner didnt like it.. didnt like the idea of having things hosted externally, however, now he wants good apps..

Comment: i have edited the main question with additional details of our current setup. appreciate all answer so far. thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Given your question is very 'open' and unspecific perhaps [THIS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_office_suites#Comparison_of_general_and_technical_information) wikipedia breakdown of the market segment may be of use.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you try the 30 day free trial for [Google Apps](https://www.google.com/a/cpanel/premier/new) as this is the best way to answer your questions hands-on. I just migrated my domain over to Google Apps, but use it mainly for Gmail. I got tired of my web hosting provider getting in the Spam RBL databases periodically.

Google recently changed the free trial to one of those "you must cancel" trials, but I tried it back several months ago went it was no strings attached.